# Is it possible to receive an event when a new resource is created

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

I would like to run some automation to take some actions whenever a new resource is created in One of my subscriptions in Azure. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I can see that you are new here and might want to look at the tour link:
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Unfortunately such a question is off-topic: There is no "best" way, and this really is a documentation request. That said: consider looking into Event Grid. Then, I'd suggest posting specific questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks .. sorry to bother you guys by making it look like not a question.. I am already doing activity logs based architecture.. but major problem I have is to distinguish a resource on if it is new one or existing one

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Event grid for this, a solution that is built for exactly this purpose. Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview

> Azure Event Grid allows you to easily build applications with event-based architectures. You select the Azure resource you would like to subscribe to, and give the event handler or WebHook endpoint to send the event to. Event Grid has built-in support for events coming from Azure services, like storage blobs and resource groups.

You basically create a subscription to a certain event (such as specific resources being created) that can then be picked up by a webhook, or processed by Azure Automation or Azure Functions

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I am already doing this with two azure functions.. one is http function which is provided in the alert settings of activity logs, which does post it to azure storage and second azure function triggered based off queue messages, which picks up only certain amount of the messages at a time.. which is working perfectly fine.. however major problem is that I am not able to determine from the activity log events if a resource is newly created or existing one is updated.. all I have is a write action done on a resource unfortunately